# Can I sell a figurine of iconic football moments

Tags: copyright, united-kingdom, intellectual-property, right-of-publicity, sport

I am making a football star figurine replicating an iconic goal scoring moment. I want to sell these figurines on Etsy. Is there any legal requirements for the UK where I have to say something or I cannot sell this at all? Could I also work on figurines of managers?

Edit - This is the sport of soccer

Clarification - If i were to use an image similar to this - [link](https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/detail/news-photo/steven-gerrard-of-liverpool-celebrates-after-scoring-his-news-photo/459839706?)
would buying the appropriate license from getty images suffice or would I have to find a way to license this from the club and the player as well.

Comment: To clarify, I assume that this is a question about the sport known as "soccer" in the United States and not American football (which matters because the corporate structure of the two sports is different). The particular league involved might also matter for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

### If you are making them from memory, yes

However, if you are referring to video or photographs of “the iconic moment”, no. Those will be protected by copyright, including the right to make derivative works like your figurines. You would need to obtain the permission of the copyright holder.